# Js методы функции

Tags: javascript

как сделать что бы box был видим для функции

```
function Open(options) {
    var elem = options.elem;

    elem.onmousedown = function() {
        return false;
    };

    elem.onclick = function(event){
        var box = this.lastElementChild;
        toggle(); 
    };

    function toggle() {
        box.classList.toggle('open'); 
    };

    this.toggle = toggle;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function Open(options) {
    var elem = options.elem;
    var box = null; // возможно: elem.lastElementChild;

    elem.onmousedown = function() {
        return false;
    };

    elem.onclick = function(event){
        box = this.lastElementChild;
        toggle(); 
    };

    function toggle() {
        if (box)
          box.classList.toggle('open'); 
    };

    this.toggle = toggle;
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry Filippov, поставьте галочку или задайте дополнительный вопрос если что-то не ясно